# Trouble understanding the definition of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a very simple, probably silly, question, but I'm having a diffuclty in unerstanding the terminology used in definition of a subspace.

From Wikipedia:

> If $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$ and if $W$ is a subset of $V$, then
>   $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if under the operations of $V$, $W$ is a vector space
>   over $K$.

To me, the first sentence seems to be using two different (though related) terms interchangeably: "space" and a "subset".

In other words, why is it correct to say that "$W$ is *subset* of $V$", when $V$ is not merely a (super)set but a space? Am I being too pedantic over the phrasing?

Comment: The words space and subspace have different meanings in different subjects. E.g. there are topological spaces and topological subspaces. In the context of vector spaces it  is better to say vector subspace. Especially when talking about topological vector spaces.  Actually $V$ is not a vector space, although we often do say that. A vector space over a field $\Bbb F=(F,+_{\Bbb F}, \times_{\Bbb F})$ is $\Bbb V=(V,\Bbb F, +,\times)$ where $+$ is addition in $V$ and $\times $ is multiplication of members of $V$ by members of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset of $V$ is any set that has no element not belonging to $V$. No matter what operations or relations $V$ has.

Now, if $W$ is a subset of $V$ and if the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ inherited from $V$ make $W$ a vector space, then $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

For example, if $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $W=\{(0,2),(1,4)\}$ then $W$ is a subset of $V$, but it is not a subspace because $(0,2)+(1,4)\notin W$.

Comment: So $V$ is a *space* and a *(super)set* at the same time, right?